# Collapsed menu in bootstrap with multiple columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to customize the bootstrap standard navbar for multicolumn support in collapsed mode, I want 3 columns in the tablet version and the normal 1 column in the smartphone.

Any ideas or links to a solution? I am new to bootstrap and have trouble figuring this out.

Comment: Hi.  I dont know boostrap myself but what have you tried so far?  Have you got any code to post?

Comment: what you tried to solve this problem... post your code so that we can help you..

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
}
```

try this css code

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Juan Coder!

This was almost exactly what I needed. For it to work perfectly for me I had to add this rule as well:

```
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete answer combining the ones from Juan Coder and Allan Rasmussen:

```
/* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { 

    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

You can also change the media query to any size you'd like:

[Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries)

[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)